# I Tried do a simple unit testing in mvc 2 but it throws this error .Can any one Help me

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2010, unit-testing

I have to do a unit test for one method or function in MVC 2 .It will work on windows application  ,But it shows the following  Error Message in mvc2 can any one help me please

The Web request 'LocalHost' completed successfully without running the test. This can occur when configuring the Web application for testing fails (an ASP.NET server error occurs when processing the request), or when no ASP.NET page is executed (the URL may point to an HTML page, a Web service, or a directory listing). Running tests in ASP.NET requires the URL to resolve to an ASP.NET page and for the page to execute properly up to the Load event. The response from the request is stored in the file 'WebRequestResponse_HelloTest.html' with the test results; typically this file can be opened with a Web browser to view its contents.

here is my code Below

Home Controller:

```
 public string Hello()
        {
            return  "This is my First Unit Testing";
        }
```

After that Right Click the controller , select the specified method and done a unit testing.

Here the testing Code below
HomeControllerTest.cs

```
  [TestMethod()]
        [HostType("ASP.NET")]
        [AspNetDevelopmentServerHost("C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\praveen\\adcd\\adcd", "/")]
        [UrlToTest("http://localhost:50332/")]
        public void HelloTest()
        {
            HomeController target = new HomeController(); // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string expected = "This IS my First Unit Testing"; // TODO: Initialize to an appropriate value
            string actual;
            actual = target.Hello();
            Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual);
          //  Assert.Inconclusive("Verify the correctness of this test method.");
        }

TestFiles:
WebRequestResponse_HelloTest.html
```

Finally I got a answer once i removed a [HostType("ASP.NET")] it will check my string and show the success message.Dont know  how it works nu.Thanks for your effort to analyse my bug.

Comment: please Help some one for above question.Thanks for advance

Comment: Why aren't you just writing a unit test against your controller?  You can verify the output from the action that way to match your string.

Comment: Dont Know How to do a unit test in action.You mean that create a action for whole controller and do a unit test or else ?

Answer (score 0):

The controller is simply a class.  You don't need to have the asp.net development server running in order to test your output.  It depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your test but for me I'll write unit tests to verify my logic in the actions.  If you want functional tests where your hitting your application and your having the test interact with your app via a browser driver and code as it exists on your local IIS or asp.net development server then my example won't help.  If you want to just test your code/logic in the control then here's an example of a unit test to test the output of your controller.

```
[TestClass]
public class HomeControllerTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void Hello_ReturnsString()
    {
        // Arrange
        const string expectedOutput = "This IS my First Unit Testing";
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        // Act
        string actualResult = controller.Hello();

        // Assert
        Assert.AreEqual(expectedOutput, actualResult, "Expected the result to be 'This IS my First Unit Testing'");
    }
}
```